# Ambiguous behavior of using "not" and "bool" together on an empty list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this simple implementation of Stack using Python lists. I have a small method to check if the stack is empty (list empty). I am using this method as a check condition for pop method. The pop method should raise an exception when trying to pop an empty stack. For some reason, this doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something here? Please help!

```
 __author__ = '@arun'
# Stack simple implementation using Python list


class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, value):
        self.items.append(value)

    def is_empty(self):
        return not bool(self.items)

    def pop(self):
        print self.is_empty()
        if self.is_empty:  # if not stack is empty
            return self.items.pop()
        else:
            raise Exception("Stack Empty!")

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[-1]

    def get_size(self):
        return len(self.items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stack = Stack()
    print stack.get_size()
    stack.push(23)
    stack.push(3)
    print stack.get_size()
    print stack.pop()
    print stack.pop()
    print stack.get_size()
    #print stack.pop()
```

**Output:**

```
0
2
False
3
False
23
0
```

Why is pop() method popping out elements when is_empty() is returning False?!

Comment: As a side note, why do the check in the first place? If it's not empty, the `pop` will work. If it _is_ empty, the `pop` will raise an `Exception`. So… you're done. If you want to wrap or replace the extension with a more specific type (although in your case, you're using a _less_ specific type!), just use a `try`/`except` to handle it and throw something new. In Python, [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) programming is often easier than [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl).

Comment: @abarnert thanks for your valuable insight! the more I learn, the more it fascinates me! Love Python!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if self.is_empty:
```

will always evaluate to `True`, since it is a [Truthy value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). You need to call the function like this

```
if self.is_empty():
```

And **a suggestion:** You might want to `pop` the values only when `is_empty()` is `False`, like this

```
if not self.is_empty():
```

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks! that's interesting!

Comment: @zhangyangyu Yup :) Updated my answer :)

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar You are welcome :) And please check the suggestion made in the answer.